# If $a \in \mathbb{C}$, is $|a|^2=\bar{a}a=a\bar{a} \in \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

If $a \in \mathbb{C}$, is $|a|^2=\bar{a}a=a\bar{a} \in \mathbb{R}$?

Meaning, if I have a complex number and I multiply it by its complex conjugate, would that always return a number in $\mathbb{R}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $b=a\bar a$. Then $\bar b = \bar a \bar{\bar a}=\bar a a = b$ and so $b$ is real.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because
if $a = u+i v$,
then
$a \bar{a}
=(u+i v)(u-i v)
=u^2 + v^2
= |a|^2
$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any complex number $g$ can be written as 
$g=a+ib$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $i$ is the imaginary unit.
The complex conjugate of $g$ is $\bar{g}=a-ib.$
So $$\bar{g}g=(a+ib)(a-ib)=a^2 + b^2\in \mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 0):

One could also look at the polar representation $$z=re^{i\theta}.$$

The conjugate is $\overline z=re^{-i\theta}$.

Hence $z\overline z=re^{i\theta}\cdot re^{-i\theta}=r^2e^{i\theta-i\theta}=r^2\cdot e^0$.